# How to restrict a field choice allowing only one to be populated?

Tags: 8, entities

On a basic page I have two similar fields. One for an image and the other for a video.

Either can be populated, but preferably not both, as I don't not want two fields to be displayed on the front end. I also want consistency across multiple view modes with only one being displayed in teasers etc

This trouble is, some editors do not appreciate the reasons and populate both fields, so I need to method for limiting this.

With D7 I found a good solution by using [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module. By using a select list (for the file type). the corresponding field input would be exposed in the admin and the same field would be displayed on the frontend. Even if both fields were populated, only the current selection would display.

The D8 version of conditional_fields does not yet have this functionality, and may not get it. [See my issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields/issues/2975556)

I am therefore looking for an alternative method and hoped one of the experts here might some suggestions. I am looking for something simple and could not consider anything unsuitable for an untrained editor.

Comment: You could use one field for both and restrict the field to one value. For example a media field which allows both media types Image+Video. The same is possible with a paragraph field for which you create two paragraph types for an image and a video.

Comment: Another option is to use hook_form_alter and make it conditional. Someone made a blog entry about this [Drupal 8 - Conditionally hide a form field](https://mushtaq.ch/blog/11/drupal-8-conditionally-hide-a-form-field)

Comment: @4k4 Thank you for these suggestions. I have tried both and learned new stuff in doing so, but I don't think either method will allow me a trouble free upgrade route for D7 sites.

Comment: @NoSssweat This looks more more suitable if I can get it working. A bit confusing because it is rare for me to attempt any coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A bit confusing because it is rare for me to attempt any coding.

For this example I will pretend the content type is "Article".

First go to manage fields, and add a new field of **list (text)** to your content type. Let's say the possible values are "video" and "image". So For *allowed values list*, put

```
image|image
video|video
```

In /themes/your_theme_name/**your_theme_name.theme** add the following

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function your_theme_name_form_node_article_edit_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_image']['#states'] = [
    'visible' => [
      'select[name="field_select"]' => ['value' => 'image']
    ]
  ];
  $form['field_video']['#states'] = [
     'visible' => [
       'select[name="field_select"]' => ['value' => 'video']
    ]
  ];
}
```

- Replace `your_theme_name` with your actual theme name.
- Replace `article` with your actual content type name.
- Replace `field_select` with the [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djyVD.png) of your select field.
- Replace `field_image` with the [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djyVD.png) of your image field.
- Replace `field_video` with the [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djyVD.png) of your video field.

**Lastly, clear and flush all cache to see changes.**

<sub>Source: [Drupal 8 - Conditionally hide a form field](https://mushtaq.ch/blog/11/drupal-8-conditionally-hide-a-form-field)</sub>

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you. I haven't yet done a form_alter with D8 (only did one with D7 :-). Should this code go in a custom module or in themename.theme ?

Comment: Sorry I should have read this more carefully before posting. Though I am confused about whether this will effect the needed changes in both the node edit form and the main theme. Guess I need to try and see what happens.

Comment: @MrPaulDriver you can do it in a custom module as well if you like. Here, as long as the main theme remains enabled, it will trigger the form alter regardless of whatever you use as an admin theme, which is the theme you see in node edit.

Comment: Not entirely sure what I am doing here, but I have found that putting code in my  themename.theme does not appear to work. Putting it in admin.theme does though - kind of. Except one field is always viable regardless of the selection. I am also seeing an error which appears related to a core bug connected with states.https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2700667  I've put my code and the error in a pastebin. https://pastebin.com/jDBDSTkq and https://pastebin.com/atvn593k

Comment: @MrPaulDriver you're probably doing something wrong in your theme. You're never suppose to touch any Drupal core file, that includes the Seven theme, because when you update Drupal 8 you will lose all of your seven.theme changes as this file will get overwritten by the default core seven.theme

Comment: @MrPaulDriver `Except one field is always viable regardless of the selection` double check that you used the correct field [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djyVD.png).

Comment: Understood about hacking core, I was just trying different options.You were right about field name and once corrected the error message has gone too. Still not working for my theme though nor with default boostrap

Comment: @MrPaulDriver you could go the module route. But I am sure there is something wrong somewhere. In the default boostrap did you name it `boostrap_form_node_page_edit_form_alter(`  and cleared all cache?

Comment: Yes I changed to `boostrap_form_node_page_edit_form_alter(` and cleared cache. Some big progress though. Have made a basic module (first ever) and have the form working with both `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` and `hook_form_alter()` providing that I prepend this with `seven_` . The form does what I need on this basis, but visibility not not changed in main theme, in the event of two fields being populated. This feels like a big result so far. Thanks:-) So how to make it work without specifying an admin theme? And how to change visibility on front end based on selection only?

Comment: Reading the docs, seems I change `seven_` to  module_name_` Do I understand correctly?

Comment: I am going to accept this answer because it goes a long way to filling my needs. In doing so, it seems to lead me to a couple core bugs which can be read about here https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2700667#comment-12659437. Thanks for the input and coaching.