# How to limit the display of a field on the front end, based on a Form API state

Tags: 8, forms

Following on from a [previous question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263523/how-to-restrict-a-field-choice-allowing-only-one-to-be-populated/263570).

I have a slideshow field, an image field and a video field, but I only want editors to choose one of these.

Using **Form API states** I have created a form_alter in a custom module which reveals one input field at a time based based on a choice from a select list. This is working fine. Code below.

```
    <?php

    /**
     * Implements hook_form_alter().
     */
    function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {
      $form['field_slideshow_image']['#states'] = [
        'visible' => [
          'select[name="field_selection_display"]' => ['value' => 'slideshow']
        ]
      ];
      $form['field_image']['#states'] = [
        'visible' => [
          'select[name="field_selection_display"]' => ['value' => 'image']
        ]
      ];
      $form['field_video_embed']['#states'] = [
        'visible' => [
          'select[name="field_selection_display"]' => ['value' => 'videoembed']
        ]
      ];
    }
```

This method makes for a good UI, but it does not prevent more than one field being populated. Therefore I need to extend the module to;

1). Prevent an editor populating more than one field, perhaps by displaying an inline error message.
OR
2). Limit the display on the front end, to the field which has a visible state (based on the selection list choice).

My feeling is that number 2 would make for the best UX, but it would be good to try both.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

For option #1 you would have to create a custom validation.

For option #2 which is the better solution you would have to load the fields via AJAX.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. Finding lots to read about custom validation, but much less about loading fields via ajax. Any other terms I should searching for?

Comment: I guess you could search for [this](https://www.google.ca/search?source=hp&ei=C3QxW7rRI7SQ0PEPucC-uA4&q=freelancer+nosssweat)

Comment: I  may take you up on that ;-)